# Pass the value of a text to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I pass the value of a text to a jQuery function, when I click on that text?

```
$.each(docs2, function(i, item) {
$('#body).append($('<div class="mytext">' + item.text+'</div>'));
  });


function on_text() {
var query = $('#text_box').val();

        if (query.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
   }
```

Comment: And what's your HTML? Where's the event-handler bound? You have an element with an `id` of `body`? Please consider setting up a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), for us to play with, help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you fire an event in JS you can use `this` to refer to the element fired it. So what you can do, since you are already using JQuery is `$(this).val()` in order to get the value of a text box.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b8Jad/)

Answer (score 1):

You set a parameter:

```
function on_text(param) {
   //stuff
}

//call with this
on_text($("#text_box").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Javascript onclick (or JQuery click) event/attribute using "this" to pass the element you clicked on.
You can then get the value or text in the element.